# How to make x-axis more lucid with Matplotlib?

Tags: python, plot

I have a dataframe `df`:

```
                dates        index
0               2003-01-01   0.48
1             1 2003-02-01   0.49
2             2 2003-03-01   0.39
3             3 2003-04-01   0.17
4             4 2003-05-01  -0.15
5             5 2003-06-01  -0.14
6             6 2003-07-01  -0.32
7             7 2003-08-01  -0.34
8             8 2003-09-01  -0.37
9             9 2003-10-01  -0.43
10           10 2003-11-01  -0.52
11           11 2003-12-01  -0.51
12           12 2004-01-01  -0.49
13           13 2004-02-01  -0.67
...
```

And I want to plot the index on the y-axis with the dates on the x-axis.
I used:

```
df = pd.read_csv('kcfsi.csv', parse_dates=True)
df.plot(x='Date',y='KCFSI',kind='line')
plt.show()
```

But the x-axis is really confusing. Is there a way I just can have the years on the x-axis ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `seaborn` module:-

```
import seaborn as sns 
 # Importing seaborn as sns. Now Instead of writting seaborn I will write sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('kcfsi.csv', parse_dates=True)
sns.scatterplot(data=df, x='dates', y='index')  
# here I am using scatterplot which is in seaborn module.
plt.show()
```

I hope it may help you.

Comment: from where do I import "scatterplot"?

Comment: @Dennis You need to import `seaborn` by typing `pip install seaborn.` in your command prompt. Then use the above code.

Comment: My version is 0.8.1 if this helps

Comment: @Dennis Mine version is 0.9. But I think version should not be a problem. But you can give a try by updating your version to 0.9.